# Transforming a PDE given basis vectors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, coordinate-systems

I have a non-orthogonal coordinate system defined by $\mathbf x=\mathbf x(r,\beta,z)$, and so I can find the basis vectors as
$$ \mathbf g_r=\frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial r},\quad\mathbf g_\beta=\frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial \beta},\quad \mathbf g_z=\frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial z},$$
where $\mathbf g_r$, $\mathbf g_\beta$, and $\mathbf g_z$ are functions of $r$ and $\beta$.

In this coordinate system I have written a system of PDEs, for example
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}+\rho(r)\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}=0 $$
for some arbitrary known function $\rho(r)$.

Now I want to replace the $\mathbf g_z$ coordinate direction with a new one, defined as $\mathbf g_n=\mathbf g_r\times\mathbf g_\beta$. I can write $\mathbf g_n=f(r)\mathbf g_r+g(r)\mathbf g_\beta+h(r)\mathbf g_z$, or $\mathbf g_z=\tilde f(r)\mathbf g_r+\tilde g(r)\mathbf g_\beta+\tilde h(r)\mathbf g_n$.

This is where I'm unsure what to do next. Considering the equation for $\mathbf g_z$ in terms of the other directions, I've considered doing the following:
$$\begin{align} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial z} \\
&=\tilde f(r)\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\tilde g(r)\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}+\tilde h(r)\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \end{align}$$
however this feels wrong. I think I need to use equations for $r$, $\beta$, and $n$ in terms of $r$, $\beta$, and $z$ then do the chain rule for the derivatives.

Given coordinate directions, $\mathbf g_r$, $\mathbf g_\beta$, and $\mathbf g_n$, how can I find these equations for the transformations of the variables in the PDE?

Comment: How do you define $n$? Just because you've written $\mathbf g_n=\mathbf g_r\times \mathbf g_{\beta}$ does not mean that you have defined an $n$. I suppose you want to somehow define $n(r,\beta,z)$ such that $\partial \mathbf x/\partial n = \mathbf g_n$.

Comment: I think this is my question. $n$ is a variable (like $r$ and $\theta$ in polar coordinates), and $\mathbf g_n$ is the corresponding coordinate direction (like $\mathbf g_r$ and $\mathbf g_\theta$ in polar coordinates), so if I could work out $n=n(r,\beta,z)$ that would be very helpful, I'd be able to transform my equations into this new coordinate system.

Comment: hi David, i dont know how to contact you. You are the only one who answered the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492367/how-the-authors-computed-this-limit-varepsilon-rightarrow-0-in-their-paper ... So i wonder if you could help me solving my question there. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll introduce a bit of notation to make the explanation smoother. Let's start with a coordinate system $u^i=(u^1,u^2,u^3)$. The vector field with respect to this notation can be written $\mathbf x = \mathbf x (u^1,u^2,u^3) = \mathbf x (u^i)$. I'll assume that we work in Euclidean space, it's just the coordinate system that is curvilinear. So we can express our vector field with respect to a Euclidean basis as $\mathbf x = x^k \mathbf e_k$. Thus, the coordinates $x^k$ depend on the curvilinear coordinates $x^k=x^k(u^i)$. Note I use the Einstein summation convention, meaning that whenever matching upper and lower indices appear, a sum over all possible index values is implied. In other words

$$\mathbf x = x^k \mathbf e_k = x^1 \mathbf e_1 + x^2 \mathbf e_2 + x^3 \mathbf e_3$$

Introducing the basis that interests you we can now write it in terms of the Euclidean basis :

$$\mathbf g_i = \frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial u^i} = \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^i} \mathbf e_k$$

We can also define the inverse transformation as

$$\mathbf e_k = \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^k} \mathbf g_i$$

in which $\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^k}$ is thus a coefficient of the inverse matrix of which $\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^i}$ is a coefficient. So

$$\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^i}\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^l} = \delta^k_l \text{ (*)}$$

with $\delta^k_l$ Kronecker's delta.

If we now want to define a new vector

$$\mathbf g_n = \mathbf g_1 \times \mathbf g_2$$

we can compute its coefficients with respect to the Euclidean basis

$$\mathbf g_n = \frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial u^1} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial u^2} = \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^1} \mathbf e_k \times \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial u^2} \mathbf e_l = \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^1} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial u^2} \mathbf e_k \times \mathbf e_l \; .$$

Introducing the new notation

$$\mathbf e_k \times \mathbf e_l = \epsilon_{kl}^{\phantom{kl}m}\mathbf e_m$$

in which $\epsilon_{kl}^{\phantom{kl}m}$ is the [Levi-Civita symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol), we can write

$$\mathbf g_n = \epsilon_{kl}^{\phantom{kl}m} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^1} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial u^2} \mathbf e_m = \epsilon_{kl}^{\phantom{kl}m} \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^1} \frac{\partial x^l}{\partial u^2} \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^m} \mathbf g_i  $$

where in the last step we used the inverse transformation to express the new $\mathbf g_n$ in terms of the $\mathbf g_i$.

First remark is that by construction it is clear that $\mathbf g_n$ is not a real vector but a pseudo-vector, as it is the result of a cross product of vectors. So this might lead to some trouble further down the line.

Now, if we suppose that the $$(\mathbf g_1,\mathbf g_2, \mathbf g_n)$$ form a natural basis in their own right, it should be possible to find out how $(u^1,u^2,n)$ depend on the $x^i$ because we sould have a relation of the form

$$(\mathbf g_1, \mathbf g_2, \mathbf g_n)^{\text T}(\nabla u^1,\nabla u^2,\nabla n)=\mathbb{I}_3$$

or applying the inverse of the left matrix to the left of each side

$$(\nabla u^1,\nabla u^2,\nabla n)=\frac{1}{\mathbf g_1\cdot(\mathbf g_2\times\mathbf g_n)}(\mathbf g_2\times\mathbf g_n, \mathbf g_n\times\mathbf g_1, \mathbf g_1\times\mathbf g_2) = \frac{1}{\mathbf g_1\cdot(\mathbf g_2\times\mathbf g_n)}(\mathbf g_1(\mathbf g_2\cdot\mathbf g_2) - \mathbf g_2(\mathbf g_1\cdot\mathbf g_2), \mathbf g_2(\mathbf g_1\cdot\mathbf g_1) - \mathbf g_1(\mathbf g_1\cdot\mathbf g_2), \mathbf g_n)\; .$$

Now, the same formula exists for the $(\mathbf g_1, \mathbf g_2, \mathbf g_n)$ it is in fact formula (*) above but which I'll rewrite in vector form

$$(\nabla u^1,\nabla u^2,\nabla u^3)=\frac{1}{\mathbf g_1\cdot(\mathbf g_2\times\mathbf g_3)}(\mathbf g_2\times\mathbf g_3, \mathbf g_3\times\mathbf g_1, \mathbf g_1\times\mathbf g_2) \; .$$

Note the first two vector components on the left hand side are corresponding, so we'd expect the same on the right hand side, but this leads to a contradiction. Indeed as you can see, the crossproduct of the first components of the right hand sides is

$$(\mathbf g_2\times\mathbf g_n)\times(\mathbf g_2\times\mathbf g_3)=\mathbf g_2\cdot(\mathbf g_3\times\mathbf g_n)\mathbf g_2$$

which is non-zero in general because the three vectors should be linearly independent in general. Indeed $\mathbf g_n$ is orthogonal on $\mathbf g_2$ and because of $\mathbf g_3$ being different from $\mathbf g_n$ there's no reason in general we should expect it to be in the plane spanned by $\mathbf g_2$ and $\mathbf g_3$.

So, on the right hand side, the first components lead to two linearly independent vectors in general, whereas the left hand side told us they should be equal. A clear contradiction. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I suspect that if you make a change of basis in which you consider exactly the reciprocal basis and not just change the last component of the reciprocal basis, that you will have exactly what you need.

**EDIT**: Just to put out my thought process: starting again from relation (*) but in vector form

$$(\mathbf g_r, \mathbf g_{\beta}, \mathbf g_z)^{\text T}(\nabla r,\nabla \beta,\nabla z)=\mathbb{I}_3$$

or alternatively

$$(\nabla r,\nabla \beta,\nabla z)=\frac{1}{\mathbf g_r\cdot(\mathbf g_ {\beta}\times\mathbf g_z)}(\mathbf g_{\beta}\times\mathbf g_z, \mathbf g_z\times\mathbf g_r, \mathbf g_r\times\mathbf g_{\beta}) \; .$$

If we now suppose that the right hand side of this equation forms a natural basis for some choice of coordinates $(l,m,n)$, then it should be true that

$$\left(\left((\mathbf g_r, \mathbf g_{\beta}, \mathbf g_z)^{\text T}\right)^{-1}\right)^{\text T}(\nabla l,\nabla m,\nabla n)=\mathbb{I}_3$$

thus

$$(\nabla l,\nabla m,\nabla n) = (\mathbf g_r, \mathbf g_{\beta}, \mathbf g_z)$$

On the other hand lets write $(\tilde{\nabla} l,\tilde{\nabla} m,\tilde{\nabla} n)$ for the matrix of derivatives of $(l,m,n)$ w.r.t. $(r,\beta,z)$, then

$$(\nabla r,\nabla \beta,\nabla z)(\tilde{\nabla} l,\tilde{\nabla} m,\tilde{\nabla} n)=(\nabla l,\nabla m,\nabla n)$$

Multiplying both sides by $(\mathbf g_r, \mathbf g_{\beta}, \mathbf g_z)^{\text T}$, we get

$$(\tilde{\nabla} l,\tilde{\nabla} m,\tilde{\nabla} n) = (\mathbf g_r, \mathbf g_{\beta}, \mathbf g_z)^{\text T}(\mathbf g_r, \mathbf g_{\beta}, \mathbf g_z)$$

The right hand side can be worked out to give

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
       1+H'(r)^2 & PH'(r) & H'(r) \\
PH'(r) & r^2+P^2 & P \\
H'(r) & P & 1
    \end{array}\right)$$

There are obviously no solutions $(l,m,n)$ to those equations.

Comment: This looks good so far. I have a decent working knowledge of this stuff, but I have never learnt it in a proper, structured course, so seeing it presented neatly like this is helpful. Looking forward to the rest. I had to award the bounty because it nearly expired, but please continue with the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, I'll continue. I just need some more time to work it out.

Comment: Now, it would be neat if you gave me the example you want to do in detail so that I can see if it works out.

Comment: I've edited my question with my specific example. Could you explain the $\nabla u_i$ notation, is that a gradient ($\mathbf g_i u_{,i}$)? Many thanks again for this.

Comment: That's a gradient, it's $\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^k}e^k$.

Comment: I tried to work out my suggestion in the last paragraph. But that didn't lead to a solution either. I get a set of equations that has no solution.

Comment: Thanks for all your time and effort, I really appreciate it!